# What contributes to spark driver maxResultSize limits?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, databricks, azure-databricks

In my Spark job, the results I am sending to the driver as barely a few KBs. I still got the below exception in spite of `spark.driver.maxResultSize` set to 4 GBs:

```
ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 3021102 tasks (4.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)
```

Do Spark accumulators or anything else contribute towards memory usage from one allocated by `spark.driver.maxResultSize`? Is there an official documentation/code I can refer to to learn more on this?

More details about the code/execution:

1. There are 3 million tasks
2. Each task reads 50 files from S3 and re-writes them back to S3 post-transformation
3. Tasks return prefix of S3 files along with some metadata which is collected at the driver for saving to a file. This data is < 50 MBs

Comment: Your number of tasks is unexpectedly huge. Can you add more to the question like the code you are running, the kind and amount of data you have. Even writing of huge files can also cause this issue.

Comment: thanks, @MohdAvais. added details. number of tasks is 3 million. not sure if that explains the exhaustion of 4 GBs of allocated mem.

Comment: The limit here is for sum of output from all the 3 million result tasks. Is the total of them less than 50 MB? What version of spark you are using? There was an issue with accumulators in earlier versions: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837
Also, can you try reducing the partitions and try. Another way out is to set spark.driver.maxResultSize to 0 for unlimited size(not recommended though).

Comment: Yes, the total of what see saved in the file from the collected output is less than 50 MB. I'm using Spark 2.4.x

Comment: In that case, can you check if you are using any accumulators or broadcasting something. Also, caching any dataframe? Because caching a dataframe will cause it to be converted to column based RDD and collect the min and maximum value of each column and send it back to driver for statistics. Meanwhile, can you try repartitioning to lower partitions or try with 0 as the flag value?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/37713): the cause is that when Spark calculates result size it actually also counts metadata(like metrics) in the task binary result sent back to driver. Therefore in case you have huge amount of tasks but collect almost nothing(the real data), you might still hit the error.